# What device to remove pulp from sloe gin

Tags: filtering, straining

I've made my sloe gin and like the taste, now I want to strain off the berries and residue to leave a clear product that wont keep getting a stronger flavour.

There are all sorts of filters and strainers available. I've seen coffee filters and muslin cloth. I'm not looking for specific product recommendations, but to know what class of product is ideal for leaving a crystal clear gin.

Comment: You might want to ask on [homebrew.se]... I think this topic is slightly closer to their wheelhouse (though arguably on topic at either site).

Comment: When using a fine filter, you probably want to pre-filter out the big lumps, so you might, for example, use a coarse sieve then your ideal filter

Answer (score 2):

I think following should do:

- first: coars filter to get out the big stuff
- second: coffee filter to remove the finer stuff
- optional: you could leave the gin standing for a few days in cold, this should cause the remaining sludge to settle. Then siphone off the clear part with a food safe tube into the bottles.